# preg_replace conditional replacement with different string

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I know there's a if/then in the matching of regular expressions, but is there one in the replace?

ie. I want to do in one regex

> "I have Foo Bars under $5 for sale" to be "Foo Bars~$5"
>
> "I have Foo Bars for sale" to become "Foo Bars" and NOT "Foo Bars~"

I have an expression a bit like this at the moment:

```
preg_replace("/(([A-Z][a-z]*\s){1,3})((under .)\d+)?/","$1~$4",$str);
```

(with other bits to remove the other text aswell of course!)
but that includes the ~ even when there's no 'under' in it.

I could probably use preg_replace_callback but that seems a bit OTT

Thanks.

Comment: Why not compare the strings in php then have different preg_replace expressions for them? I don't understand the why you're searching for a complicated way to solve a simple solution.

Comment: Yes, in my example I could do that, but what I'm trying to do involves parsing a page of text and I'd quite like to get it done in one regexp if possible

Answer (score 2):

Php's trim function would do:

```
// Before: "Foo Bars~$5"
    $str = trim($str,'~');
// After: "Foo Bars~$5"
```

---

```
// Before: "Foo Bars~"
$str = trim($str,'~');
// After: "Foo Bars"
```